# mysqlに大量のdumpファイルをリストアしているが、Waiting for table flushがずっと出ている

Tags: mysql

こんにちは
今大量のsqlファイル(1ファイル300MBほどのもの)をmysqlにリストアしているのですが、show processlistをすると、たまあにinsert文が表示されて、その後Waiting for table flushがずっと表示されているのですが、これは中で何をやっているのでしょうか。
tableに書き込み中とかなのでしょうか。

Comment: その大量のsql ファイルはどういった内容が入っていますか？

Comment: データとしては、一件ずつとても長いjsonデータが入ってます。
show engine innodb statusで様子を見た所、
スリープ状態になっていまして、秒間あたりのinsert件数がゼロになっていました。
リストア作業は自身のvm上で行ってたのですが、そういえばマシンリソースをあまり上げていませんでしたので、メモリ割り当てを増やし、スワップしないように設定したら、動くようになりました。

Answer (score 1):

おっしゃる通り、データベースへの書き込み待ちだと思われます。 sql 文の書き方にもよりますが、大きな sql ファイルを実行しようとした場合、その変更内容のすべてを一旦 mysql はメモリ上に保持する、というような動作を行う気がします。 flush を行う、というのは、そこまでメモリ上に保持していたデータをすべてディスクに書き出す、という操作です。これは、たとえばスワップを利用しているシステム上で、かつこの操作がスワップに乗っかってしまっていた場合、かなり遅くなることが懸念されます。というのも、メモリの内容をすべてディスクに書き出す、という作業は、一旦スワップから読み出して、それをディスクに書き直す、という作業になり、大きなファイルのコピー作業それ自体にかかる時間、が随時必要になると考えられるからです。

参考までに flush とは、データベースが、そのメモリ上の内容を、電源が落ちても復旧できるようにするために、ディスクへ永続化する作業のことを指します。

今回のように、データベースのパフォーマンスに関わる部分で不便な思いをする場合、まずその原因を特定する必要があります。 Linux をお使いである場合は、

```
vmstat 1
```

を実行すると、システムのパフォーマンスにまつわるメトリクスが、１秒ごとに画面に表示されるようになります。

コメントにおいて、メモリを増やしたら解決した、とのことですが、だとするとおそらく、 `vmstat 1` を実行してみていた場合、それは si/so (スワップイン・スワップアウト kb 数) の上昇、という形で認識できてたかな、と思います。